# What does green highlighted SQL table name indicate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql

In Transact-SQL code in Visual Studio and SQL Management Studio, some but not all table names are highlighted in green.

For example, in the following code

```
INSERT INTO library.Parameters (...
INSERT INTO library.Events (...
INSERT INTO library.EventConditions (...
INSERT INTO library.Devices (...
```

the **Parameters** and **Events** table names are shown in green but the **EventConditions** and **Devices** table names are not shown in green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters and events turn to green because it is the name of a `catalog view` - [Explanation of Catalog Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx)

Check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx).

Specifically **sys.events** and **sys.parameters** are [Object Catalog Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx), which would explain the highlighting of the table names mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighter for SQL is quite simplistic and is unable to take context into account - any symbol that has a special meaning in *any* context will receive colouring based on that meaning.

`Parameters` and `Events` are two such symbols, so they're not marked in the same way that other table names are (which use symbols with no special meaning)

In the same way, for example, in this `CREATE TABLE`:

```
create table T (
    date int,
    ID int
)
```

`date` and `ID` will receive different highlighting because `date` is also the name of a data type:

[image]